# Bound on the rank of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Prove that the rank of the Linear Transformation which multiplies elements in vector space $F^n$ to $A$ to give elements in vector space $F^m$ ($F$ being the field) is atmost $m$.

I thought of using the fact that rank is the dimension of the image.

Also, since the $n$ element set of columns span the image, and since cardinality of basis $\leq$ cardinality of span, we get Rank $\leq n$.

But this gives $n$ instead of $m$.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the right idea. The only ingredient that you are missing is the fact that $\operatorname{rk}M=\operatorname{rk}M^T$ for every matrix $M$, where $M^T$ denotes the transpose of $M$.

Comment: This fact was proved in a later class. Can this be proved without using that fact?

Comment: Yes you could also use the fact that the image is canonically isomorphic to a quotient of the domain (quotient by the kernel), hence has rank at most that of the domain. This is the First Isomorphism Theorem, have you seen it?

Comment: But will it necessarily be an isomorphism?

Comment: $Im\simeq Dom/Ker$? Oh yes, very much so!

Comment: A weaker version of that isomorphism theorem is the so called "rank-nullity theorem", which you could use here as well.

Comment: I mean isn't the first isomorphism theorem true only for isomorphisms? If so, how can we say that the given Linear Transformation is an isomorphism and not a non bijective homomorphism?

Comment: Of course not, it is true in general. If you *start* with an isomorphism then the Kernel is $0$ and the statement is empty!

Comment: Notice that the span of columns of $A$ is $\operatorname{range}T$ which being a subspace of $\mathbf{F^m}$  has at most dimension $m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise our discussion in the comments, there are three options:

1. Use the fact that $\operatorname{rk}M=\operatorname{rk}M^T$ for every matrix $M$
2. Use the First Isomorphism Theorem: for every linear transformation $T:V\to W$ there is a natural isomorphism
   $$\operatorname{Im}T\simeq V/\operatorname{Ker}T$$
3. Use the weaker version (or corollary) of the FIT known as the rank-nullity theorem: $$\dim \operatorname{Im}T= \dim V- \dim \operatorname{Ker}T$$

Comment: I don't know much about First Isomorphism Theorem. But I know rank nullity and this was actually an intermediate step in another question involving rank nullity.

Comment: The other question said to prove nullity is at least $n - m$. So they used rank nullity and said that rank is less than or equal to $m$, hence we are done.

Comment: Yes, that's all good!

Comment: But isn't this circular? Since we wanted to prove nullity is less than or equal to $n-m$ and arrived at rank in the first place.

Comment: No it's not. In question 1 you use RN to prove rank$\leq m$, *using the fact that the nullity is at least $0$*. In Question $2$ you use RN again, this time to prove that the nullity is *at most $n-m$*. The nullity is still involved but you prove something else than what you started initially with.

Comment: @Henry You're welcome!